# El Capitan: history of Word 2011 document on encrypted disk stored elsewhere?

Tags: encryption, osx-el-capitan

This is a pretty esoteric question, so I apologise in advance, but I really need to know the answer.

I have an encrypted sparsebundle in which I have a number of Word documents. I need to know that the contents of these files will remain confidential. I'm totally happy about the encryption; it's what happens while I'm *editing* the documents that has me concerned.

I only moved to El Capitan a few months ago; in that time I've noticed several extra folders/files on my system which seem to do with usage history (for want of a better term). 'suggestions' comes to mind right now, but I know there are others. No doubt yet more, which I don't even know about yet.

My question: is the content of a Word 2011 file stored anywhere in the non-encrypted part of my hard disk, while I'm working on it? If so, where?

I'm looking here more for details about El Capitan's activities, not so much Word's. I'm pretty sure Word edits in-place (and my Word neither makes backups or auto-saves for me), but with all El Capitan's efforts to be "helpful" (most of which I don't like) it seems very plausible to me that it could be saving away copies of my edits somewhere and I wouldn't even know.

I use TimeMachine twice a week, on a rotating set of 2 disks. I really need to know if there are things I should be excluding to solve this problem, but I just don't know where to start looking.

In case this is relevant, I have my Spotlight set to only index Mail & Messages, and there is nothing excluded in the Privacy tab.

Grateful TIA :-)

Comment: Sounds like you should use FDE

Comment: I'm not interested in doing that unless necessary.  The vast majority of stuff on my disk isn't remotely sensitive.  Are you saying that Capitan _is_ making copies of my edits and storing them somewhere that isn't encrypted?

Comment: I am saying Word is, as any program would, that needs the original and a copy to modify.

Comment: My experience is that Excel and Word make that copy in the same directory as the original file.  Since that directory is on an encrypted sparsebundle I have no worries about that.  As I said, I'm much more interested in what Capitan is doing than Word.

Comment: And your focus is misplaced, USE FDE for your use case and deal with the fact you have 'non-sensitive'  stuff on an encrypted disk. As much as I don't care for many of the same 'helpfulness'  thing you mention on Capitan I'd be WAY more concerned with Word and its default behavior to save a .swp or .tmp file for editing and not always doing so in `pwd` or `cwd`